# Create an infinite loop of text scroll like this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

How to create that infinite loop of text scroll like the bottom of this website? See the sample:

https://www.processform.studio/

Does require any plugin? If so what's that?

If not how to do it in wordpress?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I was so excited to recommend the `<marquee>` element, but it's been deprecated (though still supported). 

Comment: @Caleb Thank you for the response, I tried this, but not an infinite loop all the time? It's a text loop that disappears（based on how long my text is, but not infinite）, or just my method not correct?

Comment: Pretty sure there are attributes that allow for infinite scrolling. You could repeat your text a dozen or so times, to prevent whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the CSS style same as the given site
for example

```
<div class="track-horizontal-alt">
scrolling text goes here
</div>
```

on the css file need to add this style

```
.track-horizontal-alt{
animation: marquee-horizontal-alt 40s linear infinite;
```

}

for more details, you can check the given link I have found while searching
https://reneroth.xyz/marquees-in-css/

Comment: wow thank you so much! Sorry for the late response I just saw this, but this really helpful!